# use Windows registry in wine

Tags: macos, windows, wine

I want to use Putty on Mac, and I need to import Putty (SSH client) profiles in it.
Putty profiles are stored in the Windows registry (you can dump and import .reg files on another windows machine without any problem)..is there a way to import them using Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine emulates the registry so this might be more about putty being amenable to this alternate SDK.

- https://wiki.winehq.org/Regedit
- https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib

`wine regedit`

If the second link saying putty is ported is wrong, hopefully you don’t have to dump the registry and translate them to a terminal setup. ssh (as are the other tools) is native on macOS, so functionally you could ditch putty. You’d lose the graphical accordances and specific shortcuts and settings portability of course, which is what I’m guessing you want to avoid reimplementing.

Comment: I solved using `$ wine regedit`. thanks. Someone should think about a native porting of Putty in MacOS..as far as I know there are no valid alternatives.

Comment: We all use terminal to start and some people move to iTerm2 or VSCode or other IDE to get work other than ssh done. But it’s free to develop on the Mac, so maybe that’s your calling to tackle that thinking?

Comment: putty saves you a lot of time compared to bare terminal thanks to profiles, GUI for tunneling, authentication.